# Cards not going into same row on mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a card-group with several cards like this:

```
<div class="card-group">
                <div class="justify-content-start p-3">
                    <div class="card bg-light text-center p-0" style="width: 10rem;">
                        <div class="card-header justify-content-right align-middle">
                            <span class="align-middle"><h3> {{ item[1] }} </h3></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body justify-content-center">
                            <img class="w-50 m-2" style="image-rendering: pixelated;" src="../static/icon.png">
                            <div class="input-group mt-3 w-100">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-75" id="toggleButton">Water</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-25" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#timeCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseButton">
                                    <i class="bi bi-three-dots-vertical"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse mt-2" id="timeCollapse">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Time Input Dropdown">
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

When Testing on Chrome, they work perfectly, stacking into multiple rows.
However when I turn on the mobile Layouts/Narrow the Viewport, the cards start to all go into individual rows.

[image: Chrome Screen Rec]

I have tried narrowing the cards, to make sure they are not just too wide, but nothing seems to work.

What could cause this issue? Also is there a 'smart' width feature for cards, similar to css `background-repeat: round;`

Comment: Try decreasing the `margin`. However, a smarter approach would be to use `grids` or `flex boxes` depending upon the output (2D or 1D)

Comment: Also, for us to help provide your `CSS` code as well and not just `HTML` since stylings are done in `CSS`.

Comment: I have no additional CSS - Only Bootstrap 5

Comment: Also decreasing the margin does not help. As you can see in the gif nothing should be interfering, but the boxes are still going into the next row. 

I will have a look at flex boxes though.

Comment: even better, get it into https://jsfiddle.net/ as well